# Using Windows Virtual PC Images in Parallels

Tags: windows, macos, virtual-machine

I have a dual-boot bootcamp install of OSX and Windows 7 on my Macbook Pro. On the Windows install, I've created a series of Windows XP Mode installs so that I can access each IE browser in its native state. But since I develop on my OSX install I need to be able to hop between Windows and OSX quickly. For this I have chosen Parallels, but I can't open up the Windows Virtual PC images that I made for Windows from Parallels. Does anyone know how todo this?

Comment: try using a like vm software like VirtualBox. It is available for both OSX and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VirtualBox like kobaltz mentioned, you should be able to natively load and run the VHDs as VirtualBox now has native support for VHDs.  You do not need to convert them;  they should just work.